# Emacs switch Cmd and Ctrl keys

Tags: mac, emacs

It there a way in Emacs (Aquamacs) to switch the Cmd and the Ctrl keys? I'm using Emacs both in OS X and in Ubuntu (on different machines), and am having a bit of trouble switching keyboard layouts. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it. I used the following script in KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root> 
    <appdef>
        <appname>AQUAMACS</appname>
        <equal>org.gnu.Aquamacs</equal>
    </appdef>

    <item>
        <name>Switch Ctrl and Cmd in Aquamacs</name>
        <identifier>private.appdef</identifier>
        <only>AQUAMACS</only>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::CONTROL_L</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::COMMAND_L</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```